# How is the imperative of devoir used?

Tags: verbes, conjugaison, impératif

Apparently there's an imperative conjugation for *devoir* in French, and I'm trying to reason out what that would mean, how it would be used or how it could be translated to English. When do you use *devoir*'s imperative?

Comment: Incidentally, another case where you could imagine having this "double" obligation to *devoir* would be when making design decisions. "The user should have to..." Not quite an imperative, but the idea of being obligated to be obligated is intelligible :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Devoir** peut exprimer soit :

- une obligation morale ou un contrainte, il est dans ce cas synonyme de la tournure *il faut que* :

  > Tu dois obéir à tes parents.
  >   Vous devez partir tout de suite si vous ne voulez pas rater votre train
- soit une probabilité, dans ce cas il est synonyme de *il se peut que* :

  > Je dois partir demain, si tout va bien.

  Dans ces exemples on voit qu'il est suivi d'un verbe à l'infinitif (on dit qu'il est auxiliaire dans ce cas).
- soit le fait qu'on est redevable de quelque chose à quelqu'un :

  > Tu me dois 10 euros, il va falloir me les rendre.

  C'est uniquement dans ce dernier sens qu'on peut envisager l'impératif :

  > Ne devez jamais d'argent à quiconque, même à votre meilleur ami.
  >   Ne compte pas toujours sur les autres, dois ta réussite à toi seul.

If you compare with English, when *devoir* means "must" or "have to", or "might", it can't have an imperative. When *devoir* means "owe" it can have an imperative, although even then the use is rather limited.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought! Just making sure.

Comment: Just like in English, there is no imperative of owe (devoir) or should + verb (devoir + verbe). There is the negative, yes and the interrogative.

Comment: @Lambie There is an imperative of *devoir* in French. It is almost only used in negative sentences, but not always: *Dois plus que ton découvert autorisé à ton banquier et tu verras comment il réagira !*